# How to use Automapper to map navigation property viewmodels as well

Tags: entity-framework, linq, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper to return a navigation property ViewModel

Models:

```
public class Month

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public int YearId { get; set; }
    public Year Year { get; set; }
}

public class Year

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string YearName { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class MonthViewModel

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    Display(Name = "Financial Year")
    public int YearId { get; set; }
    public YearViewModel Year { get; set; }
}

public class YearViewModel

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    Display(Name = "Financial Year Name")
    public string YearName { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently have a `ASP.NET MVC` view Mapping displaying a list of Months in a table and I need to inlcude the Year Name as a column

```
public  IActionResult Index()
{
    var months =  _monthRepo.GetAll().Include(m=>m.Year);

    IEnumerable<MonthViewModel> monthsVms = MonthViewModel.MapToViewModel(months);

    return View(monthsVms);
}



public static IEnumerable<MonthViewModel> MapToViewModel(IEnumerable<Month> dm)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Month, MonthViewModel>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Year, YearViewModel>();
    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Month>, IEnumerable<MonthViewModel>>(dm);
}

//However in my view when I want to refer to the year name like below:


@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.YearViewModel.YearName)

}
```

However `item.YearViewModel` is `null`.

Question:

1. How do I setup AutoMapper to map the related navigation property ViewModel's Model to its ViewModel and include it as a navigation property to my ViewModel?

There is a 1 to 0/1 relation between the main class and its navigation property.
e.g. I want to display a list of Months with Columns Month Name and Year Name next to each other. (because I want to only use  ViewModels Data Annotations)

I found a similar question  [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e99573e-cedb-4227-8985-9b8e76bf1321/how-do-i-use-automapper-to-map-navigation-properties?forum=adodotnetentityframework) but
I couldn't get it to work

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Month, MonthViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.YearViewModel.YearName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Year.YearName));

 Mapper.CreateMap<Year, YearViewModel>();

 return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Month>, IEnumerable<MonthViewModel>>(dm);
```

but I get

> ArgumentException: Expression 'dest => dest.FinancialYearViewModel.FinancialYearName' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.
> Parameter name: lambdaExpression

I get the same problem when I try

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Year, YearViewModel>();
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Month, MonthViewModel>()
     .ForMember(a => a.YearViewModel.YearName, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Year.YearName));
```

Solution provide in answer was to map the whole navigation property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Year, YearViewModel>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Month, MonthViewModel>()
     .ForMember(a => a.YearViewModel, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Year));
```

Comment: First of all, don't build the profiles every request that's terrible :(. Second of all. In your controller add a method get sources. Which  given the entity will return object[] with each item you wish to be mapped to the VM such as object[] {entity, monthNames, etc...} loop over these and map to the vm one after the other

Comment: Was typo. Corrected. Year to YearViewModel is 1 to 1. Fields can be mapped directly to each other. ViewModel has Display annotations and data model has Entity Framework data annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this is what you want -

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Year, YearViewModel>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Month, MonthViewModel>()
            .ForMember(a => a.Year, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Year));
var o = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MonthViewModel>(new Month
            {
                Id = 1,
                MonthName = "January",
                YearId = DateTime.Now.Year,
                Year = new Year
                {
                    Id = DateTime.Now.Year,
                    YearName = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
                }
            }); // should map year as well.
```

Comment: `c dot` intellisense doesn't bring up any properties

Comment: Ah! Is that VS2013 ? can you try again ?

Comment: It's VS 2015 Update 1 and "AutoMapper": "4.1.1",

Comment: Close the solution , open again. But the syntax is that only.

Comment: I updated my original question. With what doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to map whole `YearViewModel`.Not properties of it.